# Getting an error of proc-macro derive panicked message: Invariant violation: composite constraints can only be raw or literals

Tags: anchor

I have come across this stack frame error so i decided to Box few of my account.

[image]

But when i try to Box some of the Accounts like `recent_blockhashes` `switchboard_program` i get this error. I am not sure what is the reason for this error

[image]

This is my Account Context

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct RequestWinner<'info>{
#[account(mut)]
pub raffle_account: Box<Account<'info,Raffle>>,
// SwitchBoard Accounts
#[account(mut,
    has_one = escrow
)]
pub vrf: AccountLoader<'info, VrfAccountData>,
#[account(mut,
    has_one = data_buffer
)]
pub oracle_queue: AccountLoader<'info, OracleQueueAccountData>,
#[account(mut,
    constraint =
        oracle_queue.load()?.authority == queue_authority.key()
)]
/// CHECK: Checked in CPI
pub queue_authority: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
#[account(mut)]
/// CHECK: Checked in CPI
pub data_buffer: AccountInfo<'info>,
#[account(mut)]

pub permission: AccountLoader<'info, PermissionAccountData>,
#[account(mut,
    constraint =
        escrow.owner == program_state.key()
        && escrow.mint == program_state.load()?.token_mint
)]
pub escrow: Box<Account<'info, TokenAccount>>,
#[account(mut)]
pub program_state: AccountLoader<'info, SbState>,
#[account(
    address = *vrf.to_account_info().owner,
    constraint = switchboard_program.executable == true
)]
/// CHECK: Checked in CPI
pub switchboard_program: AccountInfo<'info>,

#[account(mut,
    constraint =
        payer_wallet.owner == payer_authority.key()
        && escrow.mint == program_state.load()?.token_mint
)]
pub payer_wallet: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
/// CHECK:
#[account(signer)]
pub payer_authority: AccountInfo<'info>,


#[account(address = solana_program::sysvar::recent_blockhashes::ID)]
  /// CHECK: Checked in CPI
pub recent_blockhashes: Box<AccountInfo<'info>>,
pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anchor doesn't let you Box a `AccountInfo<'info>` type. Remove that and it should be fine.